# Elastic Beanstalk can not connect to RDS

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance that I can connect through command prompt  as follows:

```
mysql --host=rds-instance-name.ciplxctxy9hy.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com --user=username --password=password database
```

This works well. When I attempt to `eb deploy` to the Amazon Web Services elastic beanstalk instance, I get this error:

```
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR: [Instance: i-08388abd] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output:
 (TRUNCATED)...ash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rds-instance-name.ciplxctxy9hy
.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (4)
```

My `database.yml` file in my ruby instance has the following:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database
  username: username
  password: password
  host: rds-instance-name.ciplxctxy9hy.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

When I locally start the ruby server, I get no errors:

```
C:/Development/Ruby/environment-name/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production
```

What do I need to change to the rds instance or to the `database.yml` to allow me to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the security group on the RDS instance and make sure it's allowing incoming connections from your EC2 instance.